# How to derive posterior distribution for non-informative Gamma prior distribution?

Tags: bayesian, inference, count-data, gamma-distribution, poisson-binomial-distribution

Lets assume I have 1000 cases of cancer occurring per year in Barcelona. How would I proceed to estimate/derive posterior distribution for this data?

I know that posterior defined as:
$Posterior = Likelihood\times Prior$

And Likelihood defined as ->
$\frac{\beta^{\alpha}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}exp(-\beta\lambda)\lambda^{\alpha-1}$, for $\lambda>0$

Prior defined as:
$Poisson(\lambda)$

Thus we can show that posterior can be found as modified gamma distribution $Posterior=Gamma(\alpha+x,\beta+1)=Gamma(\alpha+1000, \beta+1)$

However I am not sure how with this piece of information I can derive $\alpha$ and $\beta$ coefficients? Any thoughts?

Comment: You seem to have mixed up the "prior" and "likelihood" function in your definitions.  Have you tried writing out the likelihood $\times$ the prior to see what the function looks lime?